# How to extract multiple strings into one comma delimited string?

Tags: excel, vba

I found this VBA code.

Currently the extracted strings are copied into their own column.

I would like to update the part that copies the extracted strings to put all the extracted strings in the same column (delimited by a comma).

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExtractInfoFromSquareBrackets()
    Dim wksRaw As Worksheet
    Dim strPattern As String, strRaw As String, strMatch As String
    Dim rngAllRows As Range, rngCell As Range
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngIdx As Long
    Dim objMatches As Object
    Dim rgx As RegExp
    Set rgx = New RegExp
        
    'Set references up-front
    Set wksRaw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw")
    strPattern = "(\[\S*?\])"
    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
        
    'Find the last-occupied row on the raw sheet
    lngLastRow = wksRaw.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        
    'Get all the rows into a single range for easy looping
    With wksRaw
        Set rngAllRows = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, 1))
    End With
        
    'Loop through all the rows
    For Each rngCell In rngAllRows
        'Store the value from the cell for easy comparison
        strRaw = CStr(rngCell.Value)
            
        'If the string inside the cell hits our RegExp, start the operation
        If rgx.Test(strRaw) Then
                
            'Assign the matches inside the string to an object
            Set objMatches = rgx.Execute(strRaw)
                
            'Loop through the matches, removing the square brackets and
            'writing the results to the neighboring cells
            For lngIdx = 0 To (objMatches.Count - 1)
                strMatch = objMatches.Item(lngIdx)
                strMatch = Replace(strMatch, "[", "")
                strMatch = Replace(strMatch, "]", "")
                rngCell.Offset(0, lngIdx + 1).Value = strMatch
            Next lngIdx
        Else
            rngCell.Offset(0, 1) = "No square brackets found!"
        End If

    Next rngCell

    MsgBox "Completed!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just amend the loop to:

```
        strMatch = vbnullstring
        For lngIdx = 0 To (objMatches.Count - 1)
            strMatch = strMatch & "," & objMatches.Item(lngIdx)
        Next lngIdx
        strMatch = Replace(strMatch, "[", "")
        strMatch = Replace(strMatch, "]", "")
        rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid$(strMatch, 2)
```

Comment: what I would like to accomplish is as follows...     xyzx[12], qwq[34], tio [27] - this is the source column (A). I would like to see the extraction as follows 12, 34, 27 (all in one column B)

Comment: @hazaeltom Does what I suggested not do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a submatch to get the content without the `[]`

```vb
Public Sub ExtractInfoFromSquareBrackets()
    
    Dim wksRaw As Worksheet
    Dim strPattern As String, strRaw As String, strMatch As String, sep
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lngIdx As Long
    Dim objMatches As Object, match, strRes
    Dim rgx As RegExp
    
    Set rgx = New RegExp
    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(\[(\S*?)\])"
    End With
    
    Set wksRaw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw")
    For Each rngCell In wksRaw.Range("A1:A" & wksRaw.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        strRes = ""
        sep = ""
        Set objMatches = rgx.Execute(CStr(rngCell.Value))
        For Each match In objMatches
            If match.SubMatches.Count = 2 Then
                'submatch(1) has the item without the square brackets
                strRes = strRes & sep & objMatches.Item(lngIdx).SubMatches(1)
                sep = "," 'populate the separator after one item
            End If
        Next match
        rngCell.Offset(0, 1) = IIf(strRes = "", "No square brackets found!", strRes)
    Next rngCell
    
    MsgBox "Completed!"
    
End Sub
```